# Adding custom label in vCard 3.0 using PHP

Tags: php, android, ios, iphone, vcf-vcard

I have successfully created vCard using vCard Library for PHP by `jeroendesloovere`. But I want to add some social profile links in that, how can I add that with Titles. Like it should show

```
http://faceboook.com/mthebrokenstar
Facebook
http://twitter.com/mthebrokenstar
Twitter
```

I can add this info from my phone by editing the generated vCard. I want it to generate from PHP. And also I have added some urls in vCard, and it doesn't shows any title in Android but in iPhone it shows a title `homepage` above the URLs. Like

```
homepage
http://example.com
homepage
http://example.com
```

I want to change this title to something else.  This is how I am doing this:

```
$profile = $this->common->getVcardByUsername($username);
       // define variables
        $vcard = new VCard();
        $firstname = $profile->fname;
        $lastname = $profile->lname;
        $additional = $profile->mname;
        $prefix = '';
        $suffix = '';

        // add personal data
        $vcard->addName($lastname, $firstname, $additional, $prefix, $suffix);

        // add work data
        $vcard->addCompany($profile->company);
        $vcard->addJobtitle($profile->job_title);
        $vcard->addEmail($profile->email,'Personal'); 

        $vcard->addPhoneNumber($profile->mobile, 'Personal');
        $vcard->addPhoneNumber($profile->phone, 'Official');
        $address = $profile->address.','.$profile->address2;
        $vcard->addAddress(null, null, $address, $profile->city,$profile->state, $profile->postal_code,$profile->country);
        //Peronsla Website
        if(isset($profile->website) && $profile->website!=""){
             $vcard->addURL($profile->personal,'Website');
        }

        //social
        if(isset($profile->website) && $profile->facebook!=""){
            $vcard->addURL( 'https://facebook.com/'.$profile->facebook,'Facebook');
        }

        if(isset($profile->twitter) && $profile->twitter!=""){
            $vcard->addURL( 'https://twitter.com/'.$profile->twitter,'Twitter');
        }
        if(isset($profile->pintrest) && $profile->pintrest!="") {
            $vcard->addURL('https://pinterest.com/'.$profile->pintrest ,'Pinterest');
        }
        if(isset($profile->instagram) && $profile->instagram!="") {
             $vcard->addURL( 'https://instagram.com/'.$profile->instagram ,'Instagram');
        }
       if(isset($profile->snapchat) && $profile->snapchat!=""){
         $vcard->addURL('https://snapchat.com/add/'.$profile->snapchat,'Snapchat');
       }
```

Comment: can you show how you generate the vcard and why `$vcard->addUrl("http://facebook.com", "Facebook")` doesn't work?

Comment: please check my update @Gordon

Comment: @ManojBist Have you solved this? Im having the same issue.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I'm having same issue.

Comment: @cmac no . still same

Comment: @SalmanRiyaz still not fixed.

Comment: I couldn't get it to work either. Let me know if you do. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to add Custom Labels to vCard urls by calling the `setProperty` method. I had to change it from *private* to *public* first, don't forget this if you ever update `vCard Library for PHP by jeroendesloovere`

```
    $vcard->addURL('https://test.com'); // this will have homepage label

    // Set next url and label
    $vcard->setProperty(
        'url1.URL',
        'url1.URL',
        'https://test1.com' // url
    );
    $vcard->setProperty(
        'url1.X-ABLabel',
        'url1.X-ABLabel',
        'Test 1' // label
    );

    // Set another url and label
    $vcard->setProperty(
        'url2.URL',
        'url2.URL',
        'https://test2.com' // url
    );
    $vcard->setProperty(
        'url2.X-ABLabel',
        'url2.X-ABLabel',
        'Test 2' // label
    );
```

That adds these strings to the vCard

[image: vcard strings]

On iPhone

[image: vcard on iphone]

Don't forget to update the `setProperty` function of the vCard class in vCard.php to public.

[image: setProperty function]

Answer (score -1):

I found somethind and i think it might be helpful to anyone.

`$vcard->addURL('https://www.facebook.com/username,'TYPE=Facebook');`

This way we can save the social media with URL in Vcard.

Comment: is it working for you? on Android & iPhone?

Comment: I tried your suggestion several times but not working for me on android but yes it works on iOS.
on android, it is just showing `web address` as the title.